# Circles (Area of Rectangle inscribed)

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Here's the question:A rectangle ABCD is inscribed in a circle with a diameter lying along the line 3y=x+10. If A=(-6, 7), B=(4, 7) then the area of the rectangle is?

I tried getting the equation of the circle since it passes through (-6,7)&(4,7) but then the x and y coefficient, I am unable to get.
I tried using the parametric form of the equation of the diameter so as to generalize all the points on the diameter including the centre as (t,(t+10)/3)

Edit: The points are located on adjacent sides of the rectangle.

Comment: the $x$ coordinate of the center is the midpoint of $A,B$, since the line contains a diameter, then the center must lie on the line, you have $(-1,3)$ center coordinate, then you know the length and width of the rectangle